# I have a British passport from 2006 September and going to Florida. The passport in has camera symbol. Is it valid?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, passports

I am going to Florida in a few days. I have a British passport that I acquired in September 2006. It has a "camera" symbol on front and is biometric. Just seen news items that only passports from October 2006 or later will be accepted by the USA. Is my passport valid for travel to the USA? I do have a valid ESTA.

Comment: What is your citizenship? what is the expiry date shown on the passport?

Comment: A passport from where?

Comment: How long are you planning to stay in Florida?

Comment: Depending on where you're from, you may or may not have an e-passport, which is required to travel under the Visa Waiver Program (VWP). You say that it has a "camera symbol"; is that the e-passport symbol as shown [here](https://www.dhs.gov/visa-waiver-program-requirements)? If so, you're okay to travel under the VWP (provided your passport was issued by a member country), but you'll still need to make sure your passport is valid for the whole of your period of travel (i.e. the expiry date is after you return from the US).

Comment: British passport. I have completed an eta which is fine.

Comment: I am British. I have also completed an esta form a few months ago which has been accepted. Expiring dates I'm fine.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a news item that mentions this "2006 October" valid date? From the information you've provided about your nationality, passport, and ESTA application, you should be fine. But it would be good to clarify the news item.

Comment: On the news this morning it looks like the American authorities got the dates wrong so I should be fine. There was some passports produced April time which was not biometric. . Thankyou Greg.

Comment: And thankyou Antony. The passport shown is the one I have...

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are referring to an article similar to this one from [The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2016/may/05/britons-flying-to-us-without-biometric-passports-could-be-turned-away) which the British media have been reporting since 5th May 2016.

You are right in thinking that the US 'may' turn away British passport holders if they do not have a biometric passport. However it sounds like you do have a biometric passport which were first issued in the UK in Spring 2006 so you should be fine. If you have this symbol on the front of your passport then it is biometric.

[image]

If in doubt I would contact your local passport office to clarify. There are several around the UK. If there is an issue then the passport office can create a new passport the same day (at a cost) in time for your pending flight to the US. It sounds like there is some confusion with dates being reported by the British media.